# Weblogic fastswap webinf/lib modules

Tags: maven, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, hotdeploy

We user maven to build the project and have a war module with dependencies packed into webinf/lib as jar files. The jar files are themselves configured as individual maven modules. We would like to enable fastswap for all the modules as redeploying the entire application takes a lot of time

From what I have gathered I understand that weblogic fastswap does not monitor webinf/lib dir. And also the option will be to explode the jar files into webinf/classes dir for fastswap.

In case the above scenario (exploding jars into classes folder), is it safe to do this or are there any adverse effects which can occur by following this.

I would like to know whether there is an alternative/preferred way to do this.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

WebLogic Server version: 10.3

Note: This will be done only in dev and prod the dependent modules will be again packaged under webinf/jar

Thanks.

--
Regards,
guru

Answer (score 1):

As you obviously already know fast-swap doesn't solve your issues. I would suggest looking at some redeployment solutions (e.g. JRebel) ...

Comment: I'm adding my +1 here. With JRebel it is possible to map the individual modules in WEB-INF/lib folder to update the classes are resources without redeploying the full app.